# Changing string elements between another string element in python

Tags: python, string

Let us suppose we have a string in this form,

```
xstr = 'CıCCkCnow CwCho CyCou CaCre but CwChat CaCm CıC'
```

Now I want to take each word between `C` and convert it into an upper case letter. For example, the above string should turn into

```
new_xstr = 'I know Who You Are but What Am I.'
```

What kind of algorithm is best for this job? I have come up with something, but it seems long and inefficient. Any ideas?

My algorithm was to take the index of each `C` letter. Pair them as 2. Get index values between them and then turn strings into uppercase letters based on these index. However, it is taking too long...

I thought using some kind of replace function but the strings in each `C` can be different.

Comment: Your example output does not match your algorithm description. There should be no space between `I` and `Know`

Comment: Please post your code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could capture characters surrounded by `'C'` then replace with `.upper`

```
>>> import re
>>> xstr = 'CıCCkCnow CwCho CyCou CaCre but CwChat CaCm CıC'
>>> re.sub('C(\w)C', lambda s: s.group(1).upper(), xstr)
'IKnow Who You Are but What Am I'
```

If you want to capture multi-character sequences and convert all characters to uppercase you can use `.upper`

```
>>> xstr = 'CakClsdaCpoCasdCkC'
>>> re.sub('C(\w+?)C', lambda s: s.group(1).upper(), xstr)
'AKlsdaPOasdK'
```

Comment: For instance, for this random test string `'CakClsdaCpoCasdCkC` it produces `CakClsdaCpoCasdK` which is not the correct sorlution

Comment: I am really sorry about not sharing the solution that I have expected. Not exactly but close for instance `'CakClsdaCpoCasdCkC` should have returned `AKlsdaPOasdK`